# How to extract claims from Spring Security OAuth2 Boot in the Resource Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an Authorization Server built in .Net Core Using [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)! It is working as expected to authorize clients and resources from Node Js and .Net. Now I'm trying to add a Java spring Boot 2 API (jdk 1.8) as a Protected Resource. I have achieved that goal by using the [OAuth2 Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server)! Everything works fine so far. Now, I need to extract the claims from the access token generated by the Authorization Server. This is a Bearer Token of Type JWT. The implementation I have for this is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  public String resourceId;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfiguration(@Value("${security.oauth2.resource.id}") String resourceId) {
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
  }

@Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(this.resourceId);
}

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/**/api-docs/**", "/actuator/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
  }
```

The problem is that when I try to access the claims inside a controller, they are not available. I have checked the default extractAuthentication Method from DefaultAccessTokenConverter, inside spring security, and indeed It is ignoring all non-default claims. What cross my mind is creating a new Converter extending the DefaultAccessToken Converter, as following:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

  @Override
  public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> claims) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(claims);
    authentication.setDetails(claims);
    return authentication;
  }
}
```

But I have not figured out where to inject or reference this new converter.

Comment: The current implementation works either for jwt or opaque Tokens. I would like to preserve this feature

Comment: you can read about spring security jwts here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-sansboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Spring Boot auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.java) doesn't seem to provide a way to replace the `DefaultAccessTokenConverter`, which is the default token converter in `RemoteTokenServices`. To replace the converter, you would have to replace the `RemoteTokenServices` that's created by default.

If your converter is a bean, you could set it on your own `RemoteTokenServices` object, which you can then set on `ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer` (so that it could be applied to the `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` behind the scenes):

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerProperties resource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessTokenConverter customConverter;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.tokenServices(customTokenServices());
        // ..
    }

    private RemoteTokenServices customTokenServices() {
        RemoteTokenServices services = new RemoteTokenServices();
        services.setAccessTokenConverter(this.customConverter);

        // configure based on .properties file 
        services.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(this.resource.getTokenInfoUri());
        services.setClientId(this.resource.getClientId());
        services.setClientSecret(this.resource.getClientSecret());

        return services;
    }

    // ..
```